# getting error while trying to run heroku local in windows

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am new to development in Heroku. I simply downloaded the code and was executing steps written in [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-scala#introduction).

I was able to compile using `sbt` compile stage. but when I try to run Heroku local, I am getting below error:

> Error log:
>
> [OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
>
> 11:40:11 AM console.1 | 'target' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external c ommand,
>
> 11:40:11 AM console.1 | operable program or batch file.
>
> 11:40:11 AM web.1 | 'target' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external co mmand,
>
> 11:40:11 AM web.1 | operable program or batch file.
>
> [DONE] Killing all processes with signal null
>
> 11:40:11 AM console.1 Exited with exit code 1
>
> 11:40:11 AM web.1 Exited with exit code 1

Can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Worked now. i was using heroku local only instead of pointing to correct Procfile
i.e. heroku local web -f Procfile.windows

Answer (score 2):

Worked now. i was using heroku local only instead of pointing to correct Procfile
i.e. heroku local web -f Procfile.windows

Comment: I get the same error even if I use Procfile.windows. Do you mind sharing the contents of your Procfile.windows?